# Querying Data From Last Two Years From DATETIME Field

Tags: sql-server-2008, datetime

I'm trying to pull records from a table that are from the last two years. The field is stored as a `datetime` data type in SQL Server 2008.  The query I attempted is:

```
Where ChangeWho<>N'RMADMIN'
And ChangeWho<>N'dbo'
And ChangeWhen < dateadd(year,-2,getdate())
```

I do not want any records where the `ChangeWho` is 'RMADMIN' or 'dbo' but I also only want records that have been changed within the last two years, from today's date.

Looking at my record set after the query has run, I see records from 2012 and before so it something apparently isn't correct with my ChangeWhen statement.

Any advice on how to correct it?

Thanks,

Comment: `And ChangeWhen >= dateadd(year,-2,getdate())`

Comment: Thanks, I was about to delete this question because I saw my issue. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
Where ChangeWho<>N'RMADMIN'
And ChangeWho<>N'dbo'
And ChangeWhen > dateadd(year,-2,getdate())
```